# Gluing together strings with delimiters in XSL

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have the following structure where I want to fish out the most relevant data and glue it together to make a headline.

```
<faults>
  <fault componentName="comp1">
    <introduceWhen>Time1</introduceWhen>
    <signals>
      <signal name="sig11" value="1"/>
      <signal name="sig22" value="1"/>
    </signals>
  </fault>
  <fault componentName="comp2">
    <introduceWhen>Time2</introduceWhen>
    <signals>
      <signal name="sig44" value="0"/>
    </signals>
  </fault>
</faults>
```

What I would like it to be is `comp1 1 1 comp2 0`, but so far, the best I've managed is `comp1 1 1comp2 0`, using this:

```
<xsl:template match="faults">
  <xsl:for-each select="fault">
    <xsl:variable name="compName" select="@componentName"/>
    <xsl:variable name="sigVals" select="string-join(signals/signal/@value, ' ')"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(@compName, ' ', $sigVals)"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

The solution I have doesn't feel very elegant, so if you have alternate approaches, I would very much like to see them. I also have full control over the XML, so if there are any good solutions that changes the structure of the XML, that too would be of interest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you seem to be using XSLT 2.0, you could make it simply:

```
<xsl:template match="/faults">
    <xsl:for-each select="fault">
        <xsl:value-of select="@componentName, signals/signal/@value"/>
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Or, if you want to be more meticulous:

```
<xsl:template match="/faults">
    <xsl:for-each select="fault">
        <xsl:value-of select="@componentName, signals/signal/@value"/>
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

---

Or (taking a hint from Michael Kay's answer) even simpler:

```
<xsl:template match="/faults">
    <xsl:value-of select="fault/@componentName | fault/signals/signal/@value"/>
</xsl:template>
```

The `xsl:value-of` instruction already inserts a separator between individual values; there is no need to use `string-join()`.

Comment: The second one works perfectly, I need to read up on the pipe operator!

Answer (score 2):

Isn't it just

```
string-join((//@componentName | //@value), ' ')
```

?

Comment: Wow, cool! Didn't know about the pipe operator, have to read up on that. The // thing doesn't really work, since there are other parts of the full XML file that has elements called signal (sorry about not specifying that).